# SSD vs HDD for graphic software

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, adobe-photoshop

My friend told me to buy SSD, because they are super fast and everything works super fast. Is it really that much of a difference? I currently use Western Digital Se 1TB HDD. It's my main storage place and I use it to save/open photoshop files, after effect, cinema 4d and other video/graphic editing software. How will SSD improve loading them, saving files and general usage of windows 10 ? I am looking at Samsung 850 evo ssd 128gb, because our office can get them cheaper.

Also I would like to ask - Is it possible take out my HDD with windows and all software and later plug it back to use on same computer? I want to install windows on SSD to see how much better it is. If I don't like it I can get my money back and just plug my old hdd back in!?

Comment: Yes there really is that much of a difference, it will impress you for sure. Yes you can remove your current hard drive and store it for later use in the same PC, I do this all the time.

Comment: @Moab I will give it a go then. Have never used SSD. Will the software work on hdd after removing it and using sdd for a bit? Won't there be any registry errors or serial key number errors for software or any errors at all? I don't know much about computers. I'm scared of messing up and installing all software over again with plugins. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Yes it will work, i do this routinely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSD will provide a 5-10 times improvement in disk reads - which will equate to an almost similar increase in speed in opening you files.

SSD's have 3 main benefits over HDD's - 
(1) They don't need to wait for the disk to spin to the appropriate place on
    the drive to read the data, which means lower latencies.
(2) They are faster at reading and writing, which means lower times.
(3) Higher reliability then HDD's - at least for the first few years of their
    life (figures of 10x the reliability are thrown arround)

This is not a free lunch.  There are 2 disadvantages
(1)  You pay much more per unit of storage - in the order of 20 times as much.
(2)  When SSD's fail they are more likely to do so without any warning, and
     you are less likely to be able to recover any data.  (Many HDD failure
     modes will still allow recovery of most data).

A "best-of-both worlds" approach may be to have the OS and commonly used files on the SSD, while stuff which does not require high performance or is used occassionally is relegated to an HDD in the system - so for examples, MP3's, Movies would go on the HDD while stuff which live working video/photos are kept on the SSD.

There is an option (C) you should know about - HDD's with an SSD cache.  These optimise speeds seemlessly for commonly used files.  They are a lot cheaper then SSD, and provide a level of performance somewhere between HDD and SSD.   If you are doing heavy editing through, I'd go for an SSD solution.